# Could I use the Overloaded 'new' operator with original 'new ' together?

Tags: c++

I have wrote a cpp as follow to overload the new operator.

```
    void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    //return malloc(size);
    return MemoryMgr::Instance().allocMem(size); 
}


void operator delete(void* p)
{
    MemoryMgr::Instance().freeMem(p);
}

void* operator new[](size_t size)
{
    return MemoryMgr::Instance().allocMem(size);
}


void operator delete[](void* p)
{
    MemoryMgr::Instance().freeMem(p);
}


void* mem_alloc(size_t size)
{
    return MemoryMgr::Instance().allocMem(size);
}

void mem_free(void* p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

However, in the main function, sometime I want to ues original new. But the computer always calls the overloaded new. Then I have tried the `::new`.But it doesn't make sense.
Which way that I can use both overloaded new and original new ?  Put the void* operator new in a specialized class which need to be overload new function?

Comment: "sometime I want to ues original new" what do you mean exactly? You can easily overload new for a specific class

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the global operators `new` and `delete` is an all-in game. You cannot use both your override and the original in the same program.

Comment: that's not entirely correct, as I mentioned in the other comment you can override it within a class

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Sure, but that it is not a global operator `new`.

Comment: Get it.Thanks, Sir.